# when I click submit it should change the text and update the row something is wrong there

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

good morning programers,
I have this small code which content a news control panel and I made a submit button there to active or inactive the news row so if I click on this button it should change if it's active it will be inactive it worked but there's something wrong there when I click on item one it updates the last on the table not the first on as it should do.
here is the code that I use

```
<?php
$getNewsData="select * from news";
    $QgetNewsData=$db->query($getNewsData)or die($db->error);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($QgetNewsData);
while($newsRow = mysqli_fetch_array($QgetNewsData)) {
$getActivityStatus=$newsRow['news_activity']; 
    switch($getActivityStatus){
    case 1: echo"<input style='color:red; font-weight:bold; background:none; border:0;' name='inactive' type='submit' value='تعطيل' /><input name='inActive' type='hidden' value='".$newsRow['news_id']."'/>"; 
    break; 
    case 0: echo"<input style='color:green; font-weight:bold; background:none; border:0;' name='active' type='submit' value='تفعيل' /><input name='Active' type='hidden' value='".$newsRow['news_id']."'/>"; break;}
    }
if(isset($_POST['inactive'])){
            $inActive=$_POST['inActive'];
            echo $inActive;
        $updateStatus="UPDATE news SET news_activity=0 WHERE news_id='".$inActive."' ";
        $QupdateStatus=$db->query($updateStatus)or die($db->error);
        if($QupdateStatus){ 
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['active'])){
            $Active=$_POST['Active'];
            echo $Active;
        $updateStatus="UPDATE news SET news_activity=1 WHERE news_id='".$Active."' ";
        $QupdateStatus=$db->query($updateStatus)or die($db->error);
        if($QupdateStatus){
        header("Location:CpanelHome.php?id=7"); 
            }
        }
    ?>
```

please any idea to solve this problem.
Thanks,
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a lot of `<input name='inActive'` and `<input name='Active'` fields. Please note that **all** of them are submitted when **any** submit button is clicked. Easiest solution I can think of is to put each pair of submit button and hidden input into separate `<form>`.

**NOTES**

Your code is pretty bad, you should consider making some improvements. For starters:

- Please format your code correctly or find an editor that will do it for you.
- Please validate POST data before using them in a query.
- Please don't glue queries from strings, instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: '$_POST['inactive']' refer to the submit button and the '$_POST['inActive']' refer to the hidden input. and same for active but it's still not working fine.

Comment: thanks the idea to put as a separated <form>  was very good and thanks for the notes will sure consider it.